# HTML Button to Update Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am trying to UPDATE a row from a MySQL Table with a button in my html page. When i press the button it outputs "Query failed". What should I change to make it work ?

My Html Code:

```
<form action="status1.php">
     <input type="submit" name="approve" value=" + ">
</form>
```

My Php Code:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
    $errmsg_arr = array();
    $errflag = false;
    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
    if(!$link) {
        die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
    if(!$db) {
        die("Unable to select database");
    }
$qry="UPDATE applications SET (status) values('1') WHERE today='$today'";
$result = mysql_query($qry);
    if($result) {
        header("location: applications-admin.php");
        exit();
    }else {
        die("Query failed");
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong syntax for an UPDATE; it should be something like this:

```
$qry="UPDATE applications SET status='1' WHERE today='$today'";
```

**HOWEVER**

You should look at moving away from the `mysql_*` functions, as they're being deprecated - you should look at using PDO or mysqli instead.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear - the statement in my answer should work. I'll edit the text.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE tablename SET fieldname=value WHERE [conditions]